# Create variables from a comma separated string

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have a variable containing these coordinates -> 40.760054, -73.991054 and I want to get 40.760054 as a variable and -73.991054 as a variable. How can I do that with less code than turning the comma separated string into an array and then creating variables from that array? I would like to not have to turn it into an array first.

Comment: The downvote means that people find you did not demonstrate a research effort, or that the question is unclear or not useful. The first and the last reason are quite evident here if you ask me.

Comment: So what did I do wrong? Did I not prove that I have tried it myself? What about the bit where I wrote “I don’t want to turn this into an array first and then turn that array into variables (which I can do). I must have done something really wrong here.

Comment: No downvote from me, but have you tried anything out yet? If so post your code up. Help us help you.

Comment: Thanks Daniel D! I will post some code now. Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to avoid creating an array, you could use this for your particular case:

```js
const str = "40.760054, -73.991054";
const a = parseFloat(str),
      b = +str.substr(str.lastIndexOf(",")+1);

console.log(a, b);
```

But really, a smart array version can be quite concise, even including conversion from string to number:

```js
const str = "40.760054, -73.991054";
const [a, b] = str.split(",").map(Number);
console.log(a, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fast, and array-free way, you can use JavaScript's [destructuring assignment syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
str = "40.760054, -73.991054";
var [a, b] = str.split(',');
console.log(b,a)
```